# How Can I Check if Date is Passed from Django Model

Tags: python, django

I am really new in Django and I want to check if Date Stored in Model is passed. In fact, I am currently working on a ticketing app where users would have to purchase and activate ticket and I want to check if the Event Ticket Date is passed upon activation.

My Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=False)
    event_venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_logo = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images')
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event_name}"

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("event_detail", args=[str(self.id)])

class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PASS, default=None, blank=False, null=False)
    added_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.event} "

    #Prepare the url path for the Model
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("ticket-detail", args=[str(self.id)])

    def generate_pin():
        return ''.join(str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6))

class Pin(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_pin, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,  blank=False)
    reference = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, editable = False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Not Activated')

    #Save Reference Number
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reference == str(uuid.uuid4())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ticket

   class Meta:
        unique_together = ["ticket", "value"]

  def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.ticket}"

  def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("pin-detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

My Views for PIN Activation

```
def pin_activation(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    
    #Create new form with name form
    form = PinActivationForm(request.POST)

    #Check if the the form has valid data in it
    if form.is_valid():

        #Check the status of the user Pin with the one in the Database
        check_pin_status = Pin.objects.get(value=form['pin'].value(), status='Not Activated')

        #Check if the PIN is correct and NOT ACTIVATED
        if check_pin_status:
     
            #Get the Pin, Ticket, Event Date
            event_date = check_pin_status.ticket.event.date
            
            current_date = datetime.now()

            if event_date > current_date:
                messages.error(request, 'Event Has Passed')
                return redirect('pages-index')
            else:
                 #Update the User Pin with a new status of Activated
                Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value()).update(status='Validated')
                #Message the User
                messages.success(request, 'Pin Validated Successfully')
                #Redirect the user to register for seat
                return redirect('register-guest')



           
        #Check filter the DB where the PIN status is Validated
        elif Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value(), status="Validated"):
            messages.error(request, 'Pin Already Validated. Register for Seat')
            return redirect('register-guest')
        #Check Filter PIN in DB where Status is Activated
        elif  Pin.objects.filter(value=form['pin'].value(), status="Activated"):
            messages.error(request, "Pin Already Activated, Login.")
            return redirect('user-login')
            
               
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Something Went Wrong. Try again')
else:
    form = PinActivationForm()
context = {
    'form':form,
}
return render(request, 'user/pin_activation.html', context)
```

Someone should help me on the best way of solving this problem because with my code for checking of date I am having **can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the date from datetime object and then compare it with the event date since your event date is `DateField` in your Model

```
event_date = check_pin_status.ticket.event.date          
current_date = datetime.now().date()
if event_date > current_date:
   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error suggest, you can't compare a datetime against a date. Your model field is just a date without any time info. Whereas you are comparing this to `timezone.now()` which is a datetime.

This is the offending line:

```py
if event_date > current_date:
```

Change it to:

```py
if event_date > timezone.now().date():
```